# SVC sentence structure confusion

Tags: sentence-structure, complements, linking-verbs, subject-complement

I have read about SVC sentences like "we all feel sorry for him".

Can I also write: The trunk wrinkled old and dry.

As wrinkle is not a linking verb so is it incorrect? Is there any other kind of sentence structure (other than SVC)that take action verb and subject complement?

Comment: This is three questions. Please pick the one you're most interested in, and ask that.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this is not a sentence; "wrinkled", "old", and "dry" are all adjectives describing the trunk, and you'd need additional words to turn it into a sentence whilst retaining these three adjectives. For example: "The trunk was wrinkled, old, and dry."

Alternatively, a verb such as "seemed" or "looked" could be substituted for "wrinkled" in your original expression.

Comment: You could interpret *wrinkled* as a linking verb, making this a sentence, although it's an unusual usage and not very idiomatic.

Comment: @standgdon, so could I use the sentence structure SVOC and change the sentence as : The infection wrinkled the trunk old and dry.

Comment: Does this sentence make sense?

Comment: @stangdom, another example in the same manner: the branches drooped weaker. Does this also make sense? I have read that certain verbs are used in SVOC structure and I am not sure if we can use "wrinkle" and "droop" in this structure.

Comment: @Learner I think your examples make sense, but they are not particularly idiomatic, and seem slightly "poetic".